# no visible interface for uinavigationcontroller declares the selector pushnavigationitem animated

Tags: iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

using instance method of pdfviewcontroller class in pageviewcontroller

```
 [self.pdfviewcontroller displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];
```

after this i need to animate the navigationcontroller of the pdfviewcontroller so i m writing this

```
[self.pdfviewcontroller.navigationController pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
```

but getting ARC Semantic issue

**no visible interface for uinavigationcontroller declares the selector pushnavigationitem animated**

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The `pushNavigationItem:animated:` method is from the `UINavigationBar` class, not the `UINavigationController` class.

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
[self.pdfviewcontroller.navigationController.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
```

Comment: My bad @rmaddy above. I removed it.

Comment: this navigationcontroller navigationbar in pdfviewcontroller is the rootviewcontroller in storyboard

Comment: Based on this pushnavigationitem it is supposed to update title on navigation bar in pdfviewcontroller. But it is not updating.